# Force Framework7 to Not Remove DOM Elements of Previous Pages

Tags: javascript, web, navigation, router, html-framework-7

It seems that Framework7 remove DOM elements of previous pages and only keep the previous one. This is problematic since the state is loss as not all interactions are stored in the backend. For example:

Page A > Page B ---> Nothing is removed

Page B > Page C ---> Page A is removed

Then when user click back twice, Page A only shows up only if Page A was fully loaded before addView() function is called. If Page A is loaded afterwards, user will not be taken back to Page A.

Is there any suggestion on how to solve this issue? I looked at the API document and didn't see any option to make sure this doesn't happen.

### Update

I managed to get it to go back to Page A by making sure div[data-page] exists before the view is loaded. However, it completely lost the state when returns back to Page A, which is completely useless. Without being able to disable this behavior, I will have a lot of extra code to store every interactions taken by user whether it's done in UI or backend. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

### Update 2

I also reported the issue on GitHub. The framework should cache final state of the page rather than original state.

https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7/issues/1985

Comment: Doesn't page A load when you click back to page B?

Comment: It doesn't if page A is loaded dynamically as in .pages div is not there after the view is already added. I have to set this variable manually. mainView.pagesContainer. Framework7 doesn't actually understand current state of DOM since it doesn't always scan through the page and this is one of the cases.

Comment: Added update on the workaround to make the page come back, but still haven't figured out how to maintain the state.